# Why is the complex exponential a Fourier multiplier?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

**Example 2.5.12.** The function $m(\xi)=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i\xi \cdot b}$ is an $L^p$ multiplier for all $b \in R^n$ since the corresponding operator $T_m(f)(x)=f(x+b)$ is bounded on $L^p(R^n)$. Clearly $\|m\|_{M_p}=1$.

(from the book "Classical Analysis" by Grafakos).

If $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i\xi \cdot b}$ is not in $L^{\infty}$ (for some $b$). Why is $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i\xi \cdot b}$ an $L^p$ multiplier?

Comment: The norm of a complex exponential is always $1$ ... how could it be unbounded?

Comment: I forgot that there was the imaginary number i